# HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail

I have been using Gmail API to automatic email processing in production for many months now. All of a sudden since July 2, 2020 seeing the error message trying to access Gmail API.

> HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned
> "The caller does not have permission"

Checked Gmail Dashboard and the credentials are active noting was removed or modified.

Checked code and can confirm nothing changed for 3-4 months.

And we are not using old token. Our code takes care of expired credentials and does a token refresh.

[image]

Also tried removing the `token.pickle` file, when rerun re-authenticated using the Gmail Auth screen and `token.pickle` file is recreated however the error message cannot be resolved.

It looks like something changed in Google's end.

Can someone please confirm ?

When doing a search seems lot of ppl are seeing this in various APIs recently but no viable solution is provided.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: Same here. Thank you, I thought I was crazy.

Answer (score 8):

This is a system-wide issue on Google's side: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160441983

Answer (score 1):

logged against python api here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/959. they seemed to be responsive before

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround using a local copy of the discovery json file posted in the thread yihlamur linked: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/160441983#comment73. The workaround was successful for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday aswell. The issue has since been resolved. See - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160441983