# admin sdk delegate email error 403 "The caller does not have permission"

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When trying to delegate a user's email inbox access to another user, a HttpError 403 occurs and says "The caller does not have permission". What is going on?

entered in: gam user marc delegate to anitha@rainforestapp.com

```
ERROR: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission">'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761519/httperror-403-when-requesting-https-www-googleapis-com-discovery-v1-apis-gmail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thread related to this. Seems to be an issue on Google's side.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62762112/13879863